# Post Multiple Form Values with PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I have this form and out of this form, I can get 2 values from the radio buttons with post. But, I want to able to send another value winch is in my while loop the `$fieldname` variable with my form. I just don't know how to do that.

This my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Velden");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div>";
echo "<h1>".$row['name']."</h1>";
echo "<h3>".$row['locatie']."</h3>";
echo '<img src="images/'.$row['photo'].'" width="120px" height="120px"/>'; 
echo "<p>".$row['aanwezig']."</p>";
$namefield = $row['name'];
$players = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, user_status FROM veld_user WHERE      user_status=1 AND name='$namefield'");  
echo "veld: ".$row['name']."<br />";
$number = mysqli_num_rows($players);
echo "Aantal spelers aanwezig: ".$number."<br /><br />";    
?>
<form action="" method="post" id="registerForm">
<table class="form imageFrom">
        <tr>
            <td><input  checked type="radio" name="status" value="1"/> aanwezig</td> <?php if (isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status']=='1') echo ' STATUS="aanwezig"';?>
            <td><input  checked type="radio" name="status" value="0"/> afwezig</td><?php if (isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status']=='0') echo ' STATUS="afwezig"';?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="knop"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form><?php
    echo"</div>";
  }
```

And this is the code were i get the post. And update my database

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if (isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status']=='1'){
$sql = "UPDATE veld_user SET user_status = 1 WHERE id=".$user->data()->id;}
elseif (isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status']=='0'){
$sql = "UPDATE veld_user SET user_status = 0 WHERE id= ".$user->data()->id;}
  if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
   Session::flash('home', 'update success');
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($con);
}}
```

Comment: `<input  type="hidden" name="another" value="something"/>`

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @MarcB They don't care I'm sure, but we still try :-(

Comment: @AbraCadaver: maybe we should make it a requirement to post full login details for any question involving php/mysql, so we can demonstrate what happens if they don't plug the holes.

Comment: sorry man, kinda new to this... so why am i vulnerable to sql injection..what can do to prevent it?

Comment: @EverettManuel read the link in the second comment..

Answer (score 0):

Btw thnx guys...input hidden made it work

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldname" value="<?php echo $namefield?>" />
```